# preg_match, trying to locate an array entry and clean up result... regex issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to parse some data from external site to local script. Local script cals remote page with some get data to initiate response.
Returning the required data in the headers of the remote script, in this case data is "key" string.

Now the remote page also outputs a load of other headers, the one we are after is called LicenceID
unfourtunalty the array crerated by get_headers seems to include the header title in the value, not the key. So am trying some regex to match the header value, which would look somthing like this:

licenceID: dfkfdlsdlghgsldghsld

```
function check_path($path)
{
    $headers = @get_headers($path);
    var_dump($headers);
    //while (list($key, $value) = each($headers)) 
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "$key - $value<br />"; 
    //if(preg_match('/^.*licenceID:*$/',$value))
    if (preg_match('/^.*licenceID.*$/i', $dictionary, $matches))

    {
            echo "found";
            echo "$key - $value<br />"; 
            $position = strpos($value, ':');
            $clean_value = substr($value, $position);
            $clean_up = trim_string($clean_value,":");
            return $clean_up;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
}
```

Having trouble with the regex in the line if (preg_match('/^.*licenceID.*$/i', $dictionary, $matches))

cant seem to get it to match, also needs to strip out the licenceID: from the value and only return the data after the :

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: To strip out the data use capture groups, then the id will be somewhere in the $matches[] array depending on how you did your capture groups. As for your code not matching, it looks fine, it should match anything that has the word licenseID in it, can you show an exact input? Btw, dictionary doesn't seem to be defined in that function's scope, now that I look at it... that would probably explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)():

```
function check_path($path)
{
    $headers = @get_headers($path);
    var_dump($headers);

    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "$key - $value<br />"; 
        if ('licenceID:' == substr($value, 0, 10))
        {
            echo "found";
            echo "$key - $value<br />"; 
            $clean_value = substr($value, 10);
            $clean_up = trim($clean_value);
            return $clean_up;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I just remembered get_headers has a second param, if true the key will be the header name. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: thats it! now i can target the key!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having trouble because you are returning false *inside* the foreach loop, unless `licenceID` is the first header it will always return false. Here are some simplified solutions:

---

Using [`preg_grep()`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

```
$headers = @get_headers($path);
$licenseID = preg_grep('~licenceID~i', $headers);
$licenseID = preg_replace('~licenceID:\s+~i', '', $licenseID); // clean-up
```

---

Or, like [@Glass Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487771/preg-match-trying-to-locate-an-array-entry-and-clean-up-result-regex-issue/6487813#6487813) suggested:

```
$headers = @get_headers($path, 1);
$licenseID = $headers['licenceID'];
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

so final function looks like this:

```
function check_path($path)
{ 
    $headers = @get_headers($path);
    $licenseID = preg_grep('~licenceID~i', $headers);
    $licenseID = preg_replace('~licenceID:\s+~i', '', $licenseID); // clean-up
    if($licenseID)
    {
        return $licenseID['7'];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

thanks to Alix Axel for the preg_grep suggestion and spotting the mistake in the return false else statement. of course it was always returning false! doh.